# Can I make git extract a working copy only from a remote repository?

Tags: git

As a system administrator I would like to be able to write an automated process for installation to a production server that:

- has access to a remote git repository (say on `git.mycompany.com`)
- can get a copy of one branch/label (say `release_20110721_01`) from the repository
- will not create a local copy of the entire repository

In other words, have a central repository containing all the revisions, but then install to production servers the specific tag only.

Is there a way of doing this? At least with CVS a working copy of a module with a given tag can be obtained without having to pull a copy of the entire repository.

Answer (score 4):

That is the main difference between a centralised VCS (like CVS) and a DVCS (Distributed): you always clone *all* the content of a repo, even though you can perform a **[shallow clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992611/not-understanding-git-shallow-clone)**, as [Olipro](https://serverfault.com/users/87988/olipro) [mentions](https://serverfault.com/questions/292639/can-i-make-git-extract-a-working-copy-only-from-a-remote-repository/292650#292650).

- In a CVCS, you can put everything, and get bacj only a subset of it.
- In a DVCS, you consider a repo as a global and coherent set of files, that you always manipulate as a all.

Doing a shallow clone of just one branch is possible, but complicated: See "[Partial clone with Git and Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586824/partial-clone-with-git-and-mercurial/2587244#2587244)".

But I recommend not using Git as a release management / deployment tool: "[How to shallow clone a single branch in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929688/how-to-shallow-clone-a-single-branch-in-git/4929819#4929819)".

I would rather go with **[`git archive`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html)** to zip the right branch/version you need, and then copy that to the appropriate server.

Answer (score 2):

sure, make your central repository accessible to the unprovisioned production server, perform a git clone from the server using the `-b` and `--depth` options to specify which branch you'd like along with the revision depth you want the server to have available to it.